# Validate ddslick drop down value was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I have a page I am working on which requires the value of a ddslick created drop down box be chosen in order to submit. The drop down is functioning, the value when selected passes to the target page which I am parsing the POST values with PHP.  However, I am having a issue validating this ddslick drop down box. To make sure a value was chosen before submitting.

Here is the select box that I have:

```
<select name="backing" id="backing" class="ddslick-select">
<option value="">Select Back Style</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

I am using this code to get the backing value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#backing').ddslick({
  showSelectedHTML: false,
  onSelected: function(data){
      alert(data.selectedData.value);
  }
});
</script>
```

When I submit it, the $_POST value of #backing is passing.  However I am having a issue validating it to make sure a value was selected.

In the form I have a submit button, and I validate the Quantity and the Back style via this onsubmit function:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-cart right" onclick="javascript:return validateCart();">Add to cart</a>
```

Here is the Javascript function, the Qty is validating but the drop down with ddslick is not.  If I remove the class="ddslick-select" from the dropdown which turns it to a normal drop down box, the validation works fine.

Here is Javascript function for ValidateCart():

```
function validateCart(){
var error = "";

if(document.getElementById("qty").value == '') {
    error += "You must select Quantity\n";      
}
if(document.getElementById("backing").value == '') {
    error += "You must select a Backing Design\n";      
}

if(error !== '') {
    alert(error);
    return false;
} else {
    document.productorder.submit();
}

}
```

My question is, how can I modify what I have now to validate the drop down box?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like when you instantiate ddslick it completely removes your <select> element.  I would set a hidden form element to the value of the ddslick selection in the ddslick onSelected handler.

Comment: James, could you show me a example of how this would be implemented with the code that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to validate the ddslick using this code:

```
if($('.dd-selected-value').val() == "") {
  error += "You must select a Backing\n";       
}
```